# Ajax Delete Function in Laravel doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I tried to make an ajax delete functionality in Laravel.

I cant figure out why it isnt working... There is no error but nothing happens -
 Thanks for any help!

My route:

```
Route::post('/deleteWithAjax', 'eventController@deleteWithAjax');
```

My delete Button:

```
<button value="{{$event->id}}" class="btn btn-danger btn-dell">Delete</button>
```

My javascript:

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
        $('document').on('click', '.btn-dell', function() {

        var id = $(this).val();
        var el =  $('#{{$event->id}}');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: "deleteWithAjax",
            data: {
                'id': id
            },
            success:function(data){
                el.remove();
            }
        })
    })
});
```

My Controller Method:

```
public function deleteWithAjax(Request $r){
        eventModel::find ( $r->id )->delete();
        return response()->json();
}
```

The element i want to remove is a div:

```
 <div id="{{$event->id}}">
```

EDIT**

I changed the event Handler

```
 document.getElementById("btn-dell").onclick = function()
```

now it gets fired - but i get an error in the console and the backend is still not called at all:

```
POST http://wt-projekt.test/index.php/deleteWithAjax 419 (unknown status)
send @ app.js:29
ajax @ app.js:29
document.getElementById.onclick @ home:50
```

Comment: instead of posting picture , post code instead

Comment: Yes sorry thanks for your comment! This is my first question didnt knew that there is a better way.

Comment: Does your backend code get called at all?

Comment: I just tested it - no the backend code isnt called at all.

Comment: Did you add a console.log inside your click-handler to see if it is firing at all?

Comment: You are rigth... I added it - doesnt fire at all...

Comment: I changed it now it fires but i get an error (see description under **Edit)

Comment: check in the DB if the record is deleted. @P.F.

Comment: I checked it - the record is still in the db. (The backend is still not called at all i checked that also)

Comment: Update: Thanks for all the comments! I placed the token part in the document ready function - and the error disappeared, backend calles and the record is deleted in the DB. My only last problem now is that the element is still in the view - after reloading it disappears. Any assumtion for that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problems:

1. I placed the token part in the document ready function 
   --> No error anymore, record deleted in the DB but still in the view
2. I added dataType: 'text' to the ajax call
   --> error also deleted in the View

Nevertheless thanks for your comments!